# Split data by column into corresponding sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to breakout this data from a master sheet by the number in column A into the corresponding sheets?

This task involves moving around a large amount of data frequently so a solution would hopefully be faster than manually separating out this data.

I've looked up solutions but they seem to involve using VBA or some 3rd party programs. Trying to avoid both because I don't understand VBA and I don't want to install random programs.

Example:

- LEGALENTITY: 01 goes to Tab 01
- LEGALENTITY: 32 goes to Tab 32...
- So on and so forth.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code/homework writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code/calculations you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [Ask].

Comment: I'm not an advanced excel user. I've looked for solutions and the solutions seem to be a mix of using VBA or some 3rd party download. I would like to avoid both of those if possible. I'm looking for a solution with an explanation of how it works.

Comment: @DeeDeeC I do not see a way to do this without either VBA or another programme. That being said, if the entities remain the same, you could `FILTER()` the data based on the entity in the given sheet. However, this depends on your use case if this is feasible.

Comment: @DeeDeeC Morever, a VBA-procedure to achieve this would actually be quiet straightforward.

Comment: You can use the built-in macro-recorder to automatically create the code necessary to do this.  You would have to manually do it once but after that the macro would exist and you could run it as many times as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need separate sheets at all?  Try this to split the data in one Sheet in to multiple collapsible groups.

**Step 1:** Grouping by Rows (just a single application of Sort using the column of interest)

**Step 2:** Form collapsible grouped row sets using Data->Outline->Subtotal.  Don't forget to add that extra line at the top of your data before this step.

[image]

Then you can collapse/expand/modify groups as needed.  You can also select collapsed groups (by pressing the Shift key and left click on a specific group) and copy / paste in other worksheets (if needed).